# How to remove a file if it is not used by another file

Tags: html, perl

I have to clean the directory and its subdirectories by removing all unused files. (A file is considered unused if it is not linked to in any
of the HTML files or if it is not specified explicitly that this file is in use). A file can be linked in an HTML file by either `href` or `img src`.

For example, I have an `I.html`,`1.html`,`2.html` and `1` folder. In `I.html` file, an `href` uses `1.html` and `1` directory, but `2.html` is not used by any other files. So, how can I remove the unused `2.html` file?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my($path,$regexExpression) = @ARGV;
my $fileNames = "data.txt";
my @abc= ();
if(not defined $path){
  die "File directory not given, please  try again \n"
}
print "added file ";  
if (not defined $regexExpression) {  
  $regexExpression="*";
  print "--Taking default Regular Expression. \n"
}
if (defined $regexExpression) {
  print "The regular Expression : $regexExpression \n";
  my $directorypathx= `pwd`;
  my ($listofFileNames) = findFilesinDir($path); 
  my ($listofLinks) = readallHrefInaFile();
  my ($listofImage) = readImageFile();
  print $listofLinks; 
 }
sub findFilesinDir{
  print "inside subroutines ", $path,"\n";
  my($pathName) = @_;
  my $fileNames =`find '$pathName' -name '$regexExpression' | sort -h -r > $fileNames ` ;
  if (-l $fileNames){
    return $fileNames;
  } 
 }
sub readallHrefInaFile{
  my $getAllLinks = ` grep -Eo "<a .*href=.*>" $path*.html | uniq ` ;
  push (@abc,$getAllLinks);
}

sub readImageFile{
  print "image files \n";
  my $getAllImage = ` grep -Eo "<img .*src=.*>" $path*.html | uniq `;
  push (@abc,$getAllImage);
}
print @abc;
```

I.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Index</h1>

    <a href="1.html">1</a>

    <h1>Downloads</h1>

    <a href="downloads/s.zip">Compressed craters</a>

    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

1.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>1</h1>

    <img src="images/1-1.gif" />
    <img src="images/1-2.gif" />


    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can improve your chances for a good answer if you provide a short, but complete example (including any input data). You might also provide the expected output.

Comment: In output 2.html file will move to another folder because that file is not linked with the another files.

Comment: Note that `push` returns the number of elements in the array, not the list of filenames. For example, `readImageFile` will not return a list of filenames

Comment: @HåkonHægland It is return the file names but it will return 2.html file also. I want only the name of file is I.html and 1.html and 1 directory.

Comment: @Jack What is the purpose of the `-l` test for `$fileNames`? You are redirecting output of the backticks to `$fileNames` but at the same time collecting the STDOUT of the backticks in the same variable. But the STDOUT will be empty since you are redirecting it to a file.

Comment: Also note that ``my $fileNames = `find [...] > $fileNames` `` will give a compile time error, since `$fileNames` inside the backticks is not declared yet.

Answer (score 3):

The overall approach you show is reasonable, but there is a lot to say about the code itself. The place to do that would be [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and I encourage you to submit your code there as well.

One overall comment I'd make is that there is no reason to reach so often for external tools; your program uses external `grep` and `find` and `sort` and `pwd`. We can practically always do the whole job with an abundance of tools that Perl provides.

Here is a simple example for what you need, where most of work is done using modules.

The list of files to search for in our HTML is assembled using [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule), recursively under `$dir`. Another option is the core [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module.

Even as HTML parsing appears simple in this case, it is much better to use a module for that as well, instead of a regex. The [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) is a bit of a standard for what you need here.  That module itself uses others, the workhorse being [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element)

The following program works with one HTML file (`$source_file`), for which we need to find files under a given directory (`$dir`) which are not used in either an `href` attribute or a `src` attribute in `img` tag. These files need be deleted (that line is commented out).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find::Rule;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my ($dir, $source_file) = @ARGV;    
die "Usage: $0 dir-name file-name\n" if not $dir or not $source_file;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->in($dir);
#say for @files;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    next if $file eq $source_file;  # not the file itself!
    say "Processing $file...";
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($source_file);

    my $esc_file = quotemeta $file;    
    my @in_href    = $tree->look_down(                'href', qr/$esc_file/ );
    my @in_img_src = $tree->look_down( _tag => 'img', 'src',  qr/$esc_file/ );

    if (@in_href == 0 and @in_img_src == 0) {
        say "\tthis file is not used in 'href' or 'img-src' in $source_file";
        # To delete it uncomment the next line -- after all is fully tested
        #unlink $file or warn "Can't unlink $file: $!";
    }
}
```

The statement that actually removes files, using `unlink`, is of course commented out. Enable that only once you have thoroughly checked the final version of the script, and have made backups.

Notes

- Refine what files you are looking for by adding "rules" with `File::Find::Rule`
- I use [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) on filenames, which escapes all special characters in them; otherwise something may sneak in that would throw off the regex used by `look_down`
- The code above simply parses twice through each file, assembling the lists of elements found for `href` attribute and then for `src` attribute (in `img` tag).  This can be done in one pass, by using `sub { }` specification for criteria in `look_down`
- The script must be invoked with the directory name and the main HTML file name. Please change that for proper command line parsing, and more sophisticated use, with [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

A whole lot more can be fine tuned here, both with searching for files and in parsing HTML; there is a lot of information in modules' documentation, and yet more in many posts around this site.

The code is tested for simple cases; please adjust to your realistic needs.

---

Here is a full example of usage.

I place this script (`script.pl`) in a directory with a file `I.html` and a directory `www`.

The `I.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head> <title>Test handling of unused files</title> </head>
<body>
<a href="www/used.html">Used file from www</a>
<img src="www/images/used.jpg" alt="no_image_really">
</body>
</html>
```

The directory `www` has files `used.html` and `another.html`, and a subdirectory `images` with files `used.jpg` and `another.jpg` in it, so altogether we have

```
.
├── script.pl
├── I.html
└── www
    ├── used.html
    ├── another.html
    └── images
        ├── used.jpg
        └── another.jpg
```

There is no need for any content in any of files in `www` for this test. This is only a minimal setup; I've added more files and directories, and tags to `I.html`, to test.

Then I run `script.pl www I.html` and get the expected output.

Comment: i run your program but it will not going after 10th line `die "Usage: $0 dir-name source-file-name\n" if not $dir or not $source_file;`.

Comment: @Jack That means you need to run it as: `program directory html-file`.  The `directory` there is a name of the directory under which all this is happening (you can use `.` for that, if it's the current directory), and `html-file` is the name of the html file in which you want to check for unusued files.

Comment: @Jack In the example you give in the question, it seems that this would be `program . I.html` (if all this is in the current directory)

Comment: @Jack  Added to the answer a statement of how the program is used

Comment: now I got error in  this line `my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($source_file);`. Error is `unable to parse file: No such file or directory at new.pl line 17.` the file is already there.

Comment: @Jack I don't know your files, only what you explain in the question.  Here is what I test with -- I made an HTML file which has an anchor with `href="..."`, with a name of another html file, which is in the same folder; and, it has an `img` with `src="..."` which has the name of yet another file, also there.  Both of these files are found to be used. And, for other files that are lying around it's reported that they are _not used_. (There are a few more tags in my html file, with some similar attributes, etc, for testing)

Comment: In my file 1.html and 2.html both has only img with src= "..." and links with the img folder. In I.html has only href=".." which linked with 1.html.

Comment: Now you can see my files which I just added in question.

Comment: I try to run your programme but i got this error `unable to parse file: No such file or directory at new.pl line 17.` I run the programme `perl new.pl www/ I.html` then i got that erorr. I have multiple files in that folder.

Comment: @Jack Ah, right; that is because a file is used in another HTML file with a path relative to that HTML file. Fixed, so it should now work for that.  Note that the program was meant as an example, for one HTML file.  It needs either a driver (that would invoke it for multiple files/directories),  or adjustments to work for "any" files.  I'll try to find time to edit it for that but can't do that right now. I hope that you can use it as is to at least clean up in relation to single HTML files.

Comment: hello friend.. how are you doing ..is ````File::Find::Rule```` a core module?

Comment: @stack0114106 hello :)   No, it's not.  It essentially provides a friendlier interface for the good old core `File::Find`.  (But `File::Find`'s performance is better in some use cases. There is nothing terribly wrong with its interface.) This also adds a few conveniences.

Comment: @Jack Hang on, I'm rethinking what you asked.  So, is this what you have:  This script  is in a directory where `I.html` is, and where `www/` (directory) is; the file `I.html` uses files from `www/` folder, for example as `href="www/file.html"` (etc).  If that is the case this program should work.  If it's something else please explain.  (For now I am rolling back my change, until we clarify this or I get to make more comprehensive changes.)

Comment: @zdim yes you are in right track. But unfortunately I got error. Which I mansion in previous comment.  Or you can also provide how you run your programme in your system.. In, previous comment I told you about how I run my programme.

Comment: `www/` (directory) is in `my desktop/perl/www/` and I put file in perl (directory). then I will run the programme like `perl new.pl(file name) www/(directory location) I.html(file name). If I did not put space between directory and file name that I got error in line 8. If did put space between directory and file name that I got error in line 17.

Comment: @zdim all the .html and image folder is located in the `www/ ` (directory).

Comment: @Jack Added a full example usage

Comment: @zdim Hi, Thank you providing your example. But i got same error again.

Comment: @Jack I don't know what that means -- how are your files and their locations different from the example (I mean what is the difference that matters for this purpose) ?

Comment: @zdim I try to run programme with your example and also I put only I.html file in `www` (folder).  But I got same error `Processing www/I.html...
unable to parse file: No such file or directory at script.pl line 17`.

Comment: @Jack  Please remember one limitation here: Any files used in `I.html` are referenced with relative paths and the whole script has to respect that -- if `I.html` uses `www/images/used.jpg` then the file list that the script first finds must have that (and not, for example, `images/used/jpg`).  But if `I.html` is itself in `www` then it will have `src="images/used.jpg"` so the script again must find _that_.  That means that the script should be started from the directory in which `I.html` is.

Comment: @Jack So if `I.html` is inside `www` then go inside that directory (`cd www`) and now call the script as `script.pl . I.html`.  Of course, feel free to change how command line is processed.

Comment: @Jack  One way to overcome this, and also to make this more comprehensive, is by writing a "driver" for this script -- another (short) program which calls it repeatedly (perhaps `chdir`-ing as suitable), feeding it filenames and directories so to scan your whole structure.  But it should work as it stands as well (it does for me).

Comment: @zdim Hi, If I get that output then how can i move that file in different folder? for example ` Bin/www/used.html ` like this type of output.